# SendMessage returns 0 when reading contents from notepad window using Python and Win32 API

Tags: python, winapi

I'm making a program that reads contents from a notepad window but it always returns "0". I tried to do it by multiple ways and all of them did the same thing so this is what I came up with. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import win32gui

#Message for getting the text
WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D

hNotepad = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)
Window = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hNotepad, 0, "Notepad", None)
message = win32gui.SendMessage(Window, WM_GETTEXT, 0, 0)
print(message)
```

Comment: Lparam needs to have a buffer address and wparam needs to contain the size for WM_GETTEXT.

Comment: Any particular reason you're avoiding [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32)?

Comment: Also, the class name of Notepad's child edit field is `"Edit"`, not `"Notepad"`. so the call to `FindWindowEx()` is likely returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code (on win11), your problem is that you use FindWindowEx incorrectly, the handle of the edit window is not found, **FindWindowEx returns 0.**

You can use the [SPY++ tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2022) to see the correct window name.

[image]

In win11, you need use `"RichEditD2DPT"`.

```
Window = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hNotepad, 0, "RichEditD2DPT", None)
```

In win10, you need use `"Edit"`.

```
Window = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hNotepad, 0, "Edit", None)
```

---

**EDIT**

When you use [WM_GETTEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-gettext#return-value), the return value of `SendMessage` is the number of characters copied, not including the terminating null character.

To get the Edited Text Content, you need to define a variable to store the string. The third parameter of `SendMessage` is the length you want to get, and the fourth parameter is to the string.

```
buffer=' '*255
hNotepad = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)
Window = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hNotepad, 0, "Edit", None)
message = win32gui.SendMessage(Window, WM_GETTEXT, 255, buffer)
print(buffer)
```

Comment: It still returns me 0 in message

Comment: I improved the answer, hope it helps you